# React Redux - Why should I use nested functions?

Tags: reactjs, function, redux, nested

I am working on a React Redux tutorial. There itemActions.js have below code. Why should I use nested functions? I can pass item and dispatch as arguments for the one function instead. Original code of itemActions.js and My thinking at bottom. Please explain in detail. Thanks in advance.

```
export const addItem = (item) => (dispatch) => {
    axios.post('/api/items', item)
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_ITEM,
            payload: res.data
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
    });
}


export const addItem = (item, dispatch) => {
    axios.post('/api/items', item)
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_ITEM,
            payload: res.data
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your tutorial is incredibly outdated. Modern Redux doesn't use ACTION_TYPES, thunks (like in the example) are often not written in that form anymore, you probably don't need axios, and nowadays there is rarely a need for thenable notation.
Please read [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) instead.

(There is a ton more differences that you will probably see, like reducers not being written as `switch..case` functions etc., but that's not in your code example - but you're essentially writing pre-2019 Redux)

For your question: The higher-order function in your case is a function that creates a "thunk", which is a special case of a dispatchable Redux action in the form of a function. So it's more of an "action creator function" than a "two-argument function".

A thunk would be used by calling `dispatch(addItem(item))` and Redux itself would then execute the resulting thunk. `addItem(item, dispatch)` as a notation is just not established as a pattern in Redux, and you will end up with a codebase nobody else will be able to easily grok.

Also, a thunk can read store contents, as the full signature of a thunk is `(dispatch, getState, extraArgument) => { /* do something */ }` - if you were to write that in your style, you'd end up calling `addItem(item, dispatch, getState, extra)` instead of just doing `dispatch(addItem(item))` and letting Redux do the rest.